# Problem with tensorflow and matplotlib packages when attempting MNIST dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, matplotlib, pycharm

I'm attempting to do the MNIST dataset with tensorflow as a practice exercise and am having some issues with the packages. I'm using Pycharm 2019.3.1. 
Here's my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
image_index = 7777
print(y_train(image_index))
plt.inshow(x_train(image_index))
```

I get the "no module called tensorflow" and "no module called matplotlib" errors.

Comment: The error tells you that you do not have tensorflow and matplotlib installed in the environment you use for running the code.

Comment: Please check that these packages are installed onto Python interpreter specified in `File - Settings - Project - Project Interpreter`

Answer (score 1):

The errors above indicate that you have not installed tensorflow and matplotlib libraries in your system. You can create a virtual environment or conda environment, and activate the environment, install the above libraries and run the above python program inside the newly created virtual environment or conda environment.

Comment: I did install both packages before writing any code in the directory which I am saving my files. Do I have to use a conda env no matter what?

Comment: Virtual environment or conda environment is highly desirable if you are working with different libraries in python. If you have properly installed tf and plt, you should not have any issues. But I still recommend you to use virtual or conda env. This might help you https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/getting-started.html